# WP7 - Measuring performance improvements

Tags: c#, silverlight, performance, windows-phone-7

I'd like to try and improve the performance of my app for certain tasks. There are a few ideas I'd like to try out but I'm not sure how I can quantitatively measure 'before' and 'after' performance.

What is the best way to do this on WP7? It would be nice if I could do this both on the emulator and a device.

Thanks for your help,
Ashish

**EDIT:**

I am mainly concerned with page load times. The app reads an XML file from isolated storage and populates a `ListBox`. Currently I'm using `XDocument` and LINQ to read the entire file before populating the `ListBox`.

I'd like to switch to using `XmlReader` and adding items as they are read. Ideally, the reading would happen in a separate thread, and I'd add the items one at a time (or maybe a handful at a time if that has better performance) to the `ObservableCollection` that the `ListBox` is bound to.

Thanks for the answers so far, I'll look into both the profiler and high resolution counter to time the operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [EQATEC WP7 Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/Home.aspx) will give you good timings on how your improvements are going, it'll also help you decide on where to focus on future improvements. I've only used the free version but it's certainly helped a lot.

Comment: The profiler is nice, but it has a big drawback. It always uninstalls and reinstalls the app. This wipes isolated storage and my XML file along with it. So I'll have to figure out some workaround for that.

Comment: This is likely to change in the next release so the profiler always just installs the app if possible. Question: would you sometimes like to reinstall your app, or would "always install, but offer to reinstall if installation fails" suit your need? (sorry about the off-topic)

Comment: @Richard Flamsholt: Currently, I have no need to ever re-install but I can see how such an option might be useful in some cases. But I'd like the profiler to ask for confirmation if it determines re-installation is needed. Any idea when this update might be available?

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of things you can do.

I found this post particularly useful. http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2010/10/9/basic-windows-phone-7-diagnostics.html

Also, if you have specific frame rate issues that you want to track try something like is explained here: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/07/counters/

If it is simple timing improvements I would use a more high resolution timer than the DateTime object as josh suggested.

The [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) class will give you more accurate timings

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about timing you can do instantiate a DateTime before the operation and then get the run time after it finishes and do the same for the new code.

Comment: You should use the `StopWatch` rather than just a `DateTime` to get more accurate results.